# How to Set a Typescript Enum With a data-* Attribute?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

So I have an enum like so:

```
enum AppMode {
    MAIN = 'MAIN',
    CALENDAR = 'CALENDAR',
    WITNESSES = 'WITNESSES',
    EXHIBITS = 'EXHIBITS'
};
```

I have a React component with four button with which all have their click events handled by the same function like so:

```
<button type="button" className="NavLink" data-appMode={ AppMode.MAIN } onClick={ this.handleAppModeClick.bind(this) }>Main</button>
<button type="button" className="NavLink" data-appMode={ AppMode.CALENDAR } onClick={ this.handleAppModeClick.bind(this) }>Hearings Calendar</button>
<button type="button" className="NavLink" data-appMode={ AppMode.WITNESSES } onClick={ this.handleAppModeClick.bind(this) }>Witnesses</button>
<button type="button" className="NavLink" data-appMode={ AppMode.EXHIBITS } onClick={ this.handleAppModeClick.bind(this) }>Exhibits</button>
```

Notice the data-appMode attribute is being set by the enum values. Here is handler function:

```
handleAppModeClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
   let attr: string | null = (e.target as HTMLButtonElement).getAttribute("data-appMode");
   let result: AppMode = AppMode.MAIN;
   if (attr !== null) {
      result = AppMode[attr];
   }
   this.props.setAppMode(AppMode[result]);
}
```

However the line: result = AppMode[attr]; generates the following error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof AppMode'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof AppMode'.ts(7053).

So is there a way to set the value of the result variable to the value of an enum using the data-* attribute without having to go through a bunch of if statements?